# Difference between flex-end and end?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

When I use the css property `align-items`, I cannot see any visual difference with the value of `flex-end` or value of `end`.

What is the difference between `align-items: end` and `align-items: flex-end`?

Comment: At time of writing they seem to look the same in Firefox but not in Chrome.  Was a puzzle until I found this v. helpful Q&A.

Comment: @Craig.C yeah same here, FYI for anyone wondering about that - Chrome doesn't support `end` yet, as of June 2021 Firefox and Opera are the only browser to support `end`.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

One value (`end`) is defined in the CSS [Box Alignment specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/), and is intended to apply to multiple box layout models (block, table, grid, flex, etc.)

The other value (`flex-end`) is defined in the CSS [flexbox specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), and is intended to apply only to flex layout.

With the Box Alignment spec, the W3C is attempting to establish a universal language for the alignment of boxes in CSS. Eventually, the Box Alignment values will supersede the particular values defined in flex, grid and other specs.

For example:

- `end` will be used instead of `flex-end`
- `column-gap` will be used instead of `grid-column-gap`
- and so on.

Many Box Alignment values are already in use across major browsers. But full implementation is still a ways off, so it's still safer to use `flex-end` instead of `end` (and then count on long-term support for legacy names).

Here's an illustration from the Box Alignment spec:

> [§ 8.3. Legacy Gap Properties: the `grid-row-gap`,
>   `grid-column-gap`, and `grid-gap` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gap-legacy)
>
> The Grid Layout module was originally written with its own set of gutter properties, before all such properties were unified into the existing `row-gap` / `column-gap` naming. For compatibility with legacy content, those legacy property
>   names must be supported as aliases:
>
> - `grid-row-gap` must be treated as a shorthand for the `row-gap` property
> - `grid-column-gap` must be treated as a shorthand for the `column-gap`
>     property
> - `grid-gap` must be treated as a shorthand for the `gap` property
>
> In all three cases, the legacy properties must take the same grammar
>   as the property they are aliasing, and just "forward" the value to
>   their aliased property.