# display flex not working with justify content in Edge browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following HTML in my page:

```css
.login-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-button-container">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="margin-right: 2px;"></i>
    Login
  </button>
</div>
```

Now the output on Firefox is Button shift on right side of page but when on EDGE(version 92) its showing on left side, displex flex with justify-content is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [MDN page for `justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content), it appears that there are slight semantic differences between `end` and `flex-end`, and that `start` and `end` are not currently implemented in Chrome/Edge.  A potential workaround would be to switch to `flex-end` for now:

```css
.login-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-button-container">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="margin-right: 2px;"></i>
    Login
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks. But can you explain what is the difference between end and flex-end.

Comment: @Pranjal - I wasn't able to completely understand it by looking at the MDN page, but there is [a SO post asking this same question regarding the difference between `end` and `flex-end`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654050/difference-between-flex-end-and-end); at a glance, it appears that `end` is part of a new set of layout terms intended to be agnostic to the display type, and will eventually superseded/replace display-specific values such as `flex-end`.