# What is the difference between justify-content: left and justify-content: start?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the [MDN article on `justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) they mention:

> **left:**
> The items are packed flush to each other toward the left edge of the alignment container. If the property’s axis is not parallel with the inline axis, this value behaves like start.

To me it is apparent **what is meant by property's axis**. Is it `justify-content` property's axis? And, what is inline axis -- inline text's baseline?

Practically  `justify-content: left` and `justify-content: start`, behave exactly same for me, irrespective of writing direction.

Example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  direction: rtl;
}

.two {
  justify-content: left;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container .desc {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="desc">Justify-content: start</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container two">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="desc">justify-content: left</div>

</div>
```

As seen above, in the context of flexboxes, both `left` and `start` behave exactly same. So,

**What is the difference between justify-content: left and justify-content: start?**

Comment: Try making one of the flex container a flex column and you will see the difference.

Comment: @Paulie_D I added `flex-direction: column;` on the flex-container div, and then I toggled `justify-content` between `left` and `start`. I did not see any difference.

Comment: it seems your are testing on chrome, check out the support at the end on the MDN link. Only Firefox will give you a difference

Comment: you should also understand that it's related to another specification (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/) not only the flexbox one. It's a more generic way to align in diferent situtation. A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62350959/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried in both firefox and chrome, and did not see any difference, if you want I can add a demo in the question itself. Secondly, I've heard of the new css3 box module alignment, but I don't know if `left` is not applicable to flexbox as well.

Comment: I didn't say it's not applicable. The support is still low. In my Firefox I see a difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just downloaded firefox today, and still don't see any difference on applying `flex-direction: column;` to the flex-container. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hang on, I see a difference now, but its actually about respecting `direction: ltr`.

Comment: you will see a difference in the row direction not the column one. The RTL doesn't affect the top/bottom direction but the left/right one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think chrome just fallbacks `left` to `flex-start`. Strangely, I don't understand what Paulie_D meant by his comment -- and its got 2 upvotes. https://jsfiddle.net/rpb03m4y/   shows no difference.

Comment: ignore that comment, your issue is a browser support. Try playing with the value on Firefox and you will understand the difference between all of

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654208/12614207

Answer (score 2):

```
justify-content: left
```

refers to the left direction. (always align the items from left to right)

```
justify-content: start
```

depends on the page or DOM direction (RTL, LTR), if the page is ltr then **start** refers to **left** and **end** refers to **right** (and this is why you see no change). while if the direction is **RTL** then, **start** refers to **right** and **end** refers to **left**.

Using start and end has a benefits in a website that has multiple languages or at least two languages that are different in the writing direction.

try to add `direction: rtl` into your HTML tag and see the difference.

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you'll see, I have already added `direction: rtl` in my example, and `left` **does not** start from the left of the container.

Comment: They have same `direction`, but is `left` supposed to push content to the physical left of the container or writing direction-left of the container. your answer suggests `left` doesn't respect `direction`.

Comment: I've found out your answer stands corrected for Firefox, it's just chrome that makes `left` respect `direction.